# Rotate a matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate a given figure 90 degree.

```
fig = plt.figure()
points = [[0.3036, 0.1960], [0.6168, 0.2977], [0.7128, 0.4169], [0.7120, 0.1960],[0.9377,0.2620],\
          [0.7120,0.5680],[0.3989,0.6697],[0.3028,0.7889],[0.3036,0.5680],[0.5293,0.5020]]

bird = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(points, facecolor='blue')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.add_patch(bird)

ax.set_xlim(0.2,1)
ax.set_ylim(0.2,0.9)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Axois. No, not really

Answer (score 4):

To rotate a matrix, you basically multiply your coordinates with a rotation matrix, that is given by

```
[[cos(theta), -sin(theta)], [sin(theta), cos(theta)]]
```

theta being the angle of rotation (so in your case [[0, -1], [1, 0]]).

So you just calculate the dot product like this:

```
points = np.array(points)
rotation_matrix = np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]])
new_points = points.dot(rotation_matrix)
```

and then you can plot your new set of coordinates. This is the results (after adding (0, 1) to the coordinates so that the bird is in the frame...
[image]

Comment: That matrix and subsequent adjustment is equivalent to doing `x, y = y, 1 - x`. There's no reason to actually call dot.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that your answer is lacking. I'm just adding to the understanding for OP's particular use case.